# Elastic Search “master_not_discovered_exception” centos

Tags: elasticsearch

After deleting /var/lib/elasticseach: [Corrected here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723654/elasticsearch-service-fail-after-deleting-var-lib-elasticsearch/64725081#64725081)

I had to delete it because I had some error when trying to search from an index and some stackoverflow answer stated that it was preferable to delete data path and restart elasticsearch.

I'm on centos, and Im trying to configure it for laravel scout.

When I try to do anything such as `PUT /index` or `GET /_cluster/health?pretty` I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    ],
    "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason": null
  },
  "status": 503
}
```

Here's my elasticsearch.yml

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: myCluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: myNode
node.roles: [master]
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#transport.host: localhost
network.host: 0.0.0.0
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

cluster log

```
[2020-11-07T13:03:59,571][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [NODE] path: /products, params: {index=products}
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:220) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:325) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:605) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:678) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
[2020-11-07T13:04:05,597][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [NODE] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{NODE}{2hEi19WjSn2EsdfsdfYZmmbf158Q}{ZeP6OSGJTa24ggregerghaNOMlYOng}{SERVER_IP}{SERVER_IP:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=false}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300, [::1]:9300] from hosts providers and [{NODE}{2hazEi19WjSnergza2EYgZmmbfr158Q}{ZeP6OSGJTa24haNOddMlYOng}{SERVER_IP}{SERVER_IP:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=false}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

I'm fairly new to elastic and for what I'm trying to achieve it's way too complicated.

Comment: Can you check the cluster health using this curl - `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'` ?

Comment: it gives me the same error `"master_not_discovered_exception"`

Comment: @Artas are you having just a single node in your ES cluster??

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja how do I check that? `GET  /_cat/nodes` returns the exact same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you deleted the data directory, your node never joined a cluster or was bootstrapped before, this is what it is saying in the log line.

You need to set the option `cluster.initial_master_nodes` so your node will know which nodes are the initial masters.

Uncomment the line for the `cluster.initial_master_nodes` and add the name of your node.

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["myNode"]
```

This will make your node bootstrap itself as the master.

Also, you are setting the option `network.host`, this will make elasticsearch assumes that you are running into **production** mode and will force a [series of checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/network.host.html), you need to check if you did everything in the [important system configurations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/system-config.html) part of the documentation or your node won't start and give you some exceptions.

If you are accessing your node through `localhost`, you can comment the `network.host` option and use it in the **development** mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and what I guess @ElasticsearchNinja was about to recommend helped me solve the issue.

I set `network.host` so that I can request from my home to my server. This is the solution I came upon while searching for one. If there is a better solution, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: @Artas  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547317/4039431 can be used, if you want to disable the prod-check on a single node

Comment: @Artas, let me know if you have issue disabling the prod-checks on your node, looking frwd to hear from you

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja It's all good mate, I did as your answer stated with the discovery type, I commented `cluster.initial_master_nodes` and it seems to be working just fine for now. Excetp my cluster status goes from green to red when I add an index